# Non-blocking select()?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm trying to implement simple networking game (client - server) which uses UDP to transfer game events over network, and I have this working well, but now I would like to add to game chat over tcp in same console application. I've tried to implement multi client chat using `select()` and non-blocking master socket. Chat is working as standalone application but I have problems putting it together.

Basically my server loop looks like this:

```
while(true)
{
    sendUDPdata()
    ...

    while(true)
    {
        receiveUDPdata()
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I want to add chat to server's main loop (handling UDP) like this:

```
while(true)
{
    HandleTCPConnections();

    sendUDPdata();
    ...

    while(true)
    {
        receiveUDPdata();
    }
}
```

calling `select()` in  `HandleTCPConnections()` blocks whole server. Is there any way how to handle this?

Comment: `select()` has a timeout.  You can use a timeout of 0 seconds to poll the requested socket(s) and exit immediately without blocking.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But then what does he do? He can't just call `select` again.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why not? He can call `select()` in a loop, requesting both TCP and UDP sockets at the same time. If a TCP socket reports it has data waiting, read it.  If a UDP socket reports it has data waiting, read it. One of the main designs of `select()` is handling I/O for multiple sockets in a single thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're suggesting that he just call `select` over and over in a loop, completely consuming the core even when he's got no work to do?!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I'm suggesting that if the OP wants to preserve his existing UDP loop while injecting TCP into the mix, he can use `select()` to poll the TCP socket in between UDP loop iterations. It would be better to re-write the code to let `select()` monitor both TCP and UDP sockets at the same time and let it report when any socket has data to process.  Without a timeout, `select()` will put the calling thread to sleep until any socket is ready to do something. With a non-zero timeout, the thread will sleep until the timeout elapses if no socket wakes it up sooner.

Answer (score 5):

There are two good ways to do this:

1. Use threads. Have a thread to handle your TCP sockets and a thread to handle your UDP sockets.
2. Use a reactor. Both the UDP code and the TCP code register their sockets with the reactor. The reactor blocks on all the sockets (typically using `poll`) and calls into the appropriate code when activity occurs on that socket.

There are lots of libraries out there for both of these options (such as [libevent](http://libevent.org/) and [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)) that you can use if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

`select` **is** a blocking call if there's no data available from the sockets, in your case.

Your chat can either run along with the server or in parallel with it: you've already got the first case; for the second, you'd better go for a separate thread that handles the chat. C++ has `<thread>`, which you may want to look into.

A separate thread is easier to implement in this case because you've a separate connection, and separate sockets therefore, that would otherwise need to be looked after for concurrent access.